# TensorFlow label number is a mismatch with the shape on the axis

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, classification, tensorflow-lite

trying to run the codelab:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/recognize-flowers-with-tensorflow-on-android/#6

I have developed my own files and list files although I seem to get this error when I start to run it through Android:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Label number 6 mismatch the shape on axis 1`

It then links me to this part of the code:

```
Map<String, Float> labeledProbability =
        new TensorLabel(labels, probabilityProcessor.process(outputProbabilityBuffer))
            .getMapWithFloatValue();
    Trace.endSection();
```

this is in the classification results section

```
public List<Recognition> recognizeImage(final Bitmap bitmap, int sensorOrientation) {
    // Logs this method so that it can be analyzed with systrace.
    Trace.beginSection("recognizeImage");

    Trace.beginSection("loadImage");
    long startTimeForLoadImage = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    inputImageBuffer = loadImage(bitmap, sensorOrientation);
    long endTimeForLoadImage = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    Trace.endSection();
    LOGGER.v("Timecost to load the image: " + (endTimeForLoadImage - startTimeForLoadImage));

    // Runs the inference call.
    Trace.beginSection("runInference");
    long startTimeForReference = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    tflite.run(inputImageBuffer.getBuffer(), outputProbabilityBuffer.getBuffer().rewind());
    long endTimeForReference = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    Trace.endSection();
    LOGGER.v("Timecost to run model inference: " + (endTimeForReference - startTimeForReference));

    // Gets the map of label and probability.
    Map<String, Float> labeledProbability =
        new TensorLabel(labels, probabilityProcessor.process(outputProbabilityBuffer))
            .getMapWithFloatValue();
    Trace.endSection();

    // Gets top-k results.
    return getTopKProbability(labeledProbability);
  }
```

Have no idea why this is working can anyone help??

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being late.
There may be some empty line in your labels.txt file or there may be some extra label in your labels.txt file. Do check that.

Comment: My issue was solved by this, a mismatch between the number of labels in the labels.txt file in the assets folder and that expected by the model.

Comment: Great. Do vote the answer if its useful.